# Double context switching in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am looking for the best way to deal with this case of double context switching.

```js
function myObject() {
    this.data = {};
}

myObject.prototype.each = function(func) {
    if (func) {
        for (var key in this.data) {
            func(key);
        }
    }
}

function myObject2() {
    this.data = {};
}

myObject2.prototype.someFunc = function(o) {
    // o = myObject
    o.each.call(this, function(key) {
        this.data[key] *= o.data[key];
    });
}
```

In myObject2.someFunc I use call to change the context so I can access myObject2's data. However, because of this, in myObject's each method, this now refers to myObject2. If I don't use call then I cannot access the data in myObject2.

I thought about using apply and then passing the original object as an argument and passing it back but I am looking for a more elegant solution that does not require me to change the original defition of myObject.each.

Thanks!

Comment: This code doesn't really work, right?  The "each" function should be written with `func.call(this, key);` otherwise `this` in the callback from "someFunc" won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it should be a generic function:

```
function each( obj, func, ctx ) {

    if( func ) {
        for ( var key in obj ) {
            func.call( ctx || null, key, obj[key] );
        }
    }

}

myObject2.prototype.someFunc = function(o) {
    each( o.data, function( key, value ) {
        this.data[key] = value;
    }, this );
};
```

Comment: So, simple. Guess I was thinking about this too hard. Thanks!